# Can you multiply two discontinuous functions together?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I know that you can multiply two functions together like $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x-2$. So $f*g(x)= (x^2)-2x$. But what about multiplying a discontinuous function:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} -1  \ \ \text{if} \ \ x \leq 0 \\ 1 \ \ \text{if} \ \ x > 0 \end{cases}$$

What is $f*f$?

Comment: Why should it be any different? Also, do you mean $f^2$ in the above?

Comment: f^2 is the same as f*f

Comment: Yes now it is clear since it has been edited

Answer (score 0):

$f\times f=f^2=1$, to see this look at your function as two functions $g(x) =-1$ if $x\le 0$ and $h(x)=1$ if $x>0$. Which means if $x\le 0$ we have $f\times f=g \times g=(-1)(-1)=1$ and if $x>0$ we have $f\times f=h\times h=1(1)=1$ hence $f*f=1$ for all x.

Comment: @John both the question and the answer do not deserve an up vote. I wanted to write my answer as a comment but I cannot  comment on a question until I have 50 reputation.